# Часовые пояса

Tags: время, php

Допустим зашёл на сайт пользователь из Китая. А время на сервере - московское. Соответственно он видит московское время, а не своё.

Неужели придётся гетить страну с какого-то там сайта, потом прописывать условия:

```
if($country == 'Китай') date_default_timezone_set('...');
elseif(...) ...
```

и т.д...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Использовать выбранный пользователем часовой пояс (cookies)
2. http://ipgeobase.ru/ предоставляет данные по ip/странам
3. JS как правило всегда показывает пользовательское время.

Вопрос несколько размыт, чтобы посоветовать что-то более конкретное.

Comment: Js не нужно. Видимо придется гетить и задавать.условия. Так и думал.

Comment: ipgeobase предоставляет готовые и актуальные данные. Достаточно регулярно их скачивать и распарсивать.